# Standard contracts for assets

Tags: shares

Does Ethereum have a standard contract for "dumb" assets that most common wallets understand? Mainly so that one can

- Issue new assets (one time issue)
- Distribute these assets to the accounts of shareholders
- Accounts then can freely move assets between them

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! This is a great question, thanks for asking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ethereum they are commonly referred to as tokens. Here's the official guide: https://ethereum.org/token. It is very thorough and should answer all your questions.

On the technical side, this is the EIP discussing an official API for all token contracts: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20

Interestingly I haven't found a proper answer on stackexchange in this topic yet, but there are plenty of specific questions if look for "token" or "tokens".

Comment: Any idea if (any) wallet implements this standard yet, so I don't need to come up with my own wallet?

Comment: The official Ethereum Wallet does. If you follow the linked guide it illustrates it wit the Ethereum Wallet.